# how to read the next line?

Tags: java, arraylist

```
        package project2;
        import java.io.BufferedReader; 
         import java.io.FileReader; 
         import java.io.IOException;
         import java.util.ArrayList;
        public class Project2 {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            String FirstName = "";
            String LastName = "";
            ArrayList aList = new ArrayList();

            try {
           BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\vanchi\\Desktop\\test.txt"));


                if(!br.ready())
                    throw new IOException();

                while ((line = br.readLine())!=null){
                    aList.add(line);
                    //System.out.println(line);
                    String tmp[] = line.split(",");
                    FirstName =  tmp[0];
                    LastName = tmp[1];


                    System.out.println(FirstName + "\t" + LastName);
                }
                br.close();

             }catch (IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();

           }
           /* int sz = aList.size();

            for(int i=0; i<sz; i++){

                System.out.println(aList.get(i).toString()); */
              }
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have? Is there a compile-error? An exception?

Comment: An exception Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 at project2.Project2.main

Comment: i am trying to read the lines from the text file which has two names with comma as a delimiter natalie,sophenska brad,holer

Comment: The split didn't result in two elements. Check your indata; do all lines have a ","? Remeber that a empty line is still a line.

Comment: yes there are two entries but reads the first line and thrwos me the exception

Comment: Step through the code in a debugger. If you don't know how, now is a good time to learn. Otherwise put `System.out.println(line);` before the split, to see whether each line contains a comma. But don't get into the println habit; learn to use a debugger.

Comment: what if there is a space in the next line how to include the delimiter?

Comment: can you post the contents in the file

Comment: thank you all works like magic

Comment: another question how to display contents from other text files how do i include the other files?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure each line of your file really does have at least one ','. And make your code more robust:

```
      while ((line = br.readLine())!=null){
           aList.add(line);
           String tmp[] = line.split(",");

           if (tmp.length < 2) {
               continue;
           }

           FirstName =  tmp[0];
           LastName = tmp[1];


           System.out.println(FirstName + "\t" + LastName);
       }
```

Also, I believe you don't need:

```
    if(!br.ready())
           throw new IOException();
```

You can just remove these lines.

Comment: To increase the understanding of what's actually going on, you could add a printout before continue, to tell why the row was skipped: System.out.println("Skipping line: " + line);

Comment: I think you have pressed "Enter" after the last pair of FirstName/LastName in your file. If so, then you have an empty line at the end of file. So, br.readLine() returns empty string("") for that line, and, therefore, line.split(",") returns an array with 1 empty string.

Comment: hey there i have another doubt how to dipsplay the names from multiple files?

Comment: wrap your "try/catch" section to a loop over all file names and add all lines "FirstName + "\t" + LastName" to aList or additional list of strings. Then iterate the result list and print out all items. If you'd like to have a list of unique names, then put all of them to HashSet instead. The more gracefully way is to define an additional class Person with firstName/lastName fields and override "equals", "hashCode" and "toString" methods :) I'd give you an example

Comment: @Natalie007, is there a way to send you a number of files (the whole project)?

Answer (score 0):

So, here you are :)

V1:
        package natalie.person.v1;

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.HashSet;
    import java.util.Set;

    public class RunMe {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            Set<String> allPersons = new HashSet<>(); // or use java.util.TreeSet() to have the list sorted

            File dataFolder = new File("/home/agudkov/projects/rest/Natalie/data"); // change the path, pls

            for (File file : dataFolder.listFiles()) {            
                if (!file.getName().endsWith(".txt")) { // check the file has .txt ext
                    continue;
                }

                addPersonsFromFile(file, allPersons);
            }

            for (String person : allPersons) {
                System.out.println(person);
            }
        }

        private static void addPersonsFromFile(File dataFile, Set<String> toSet) {
            BufferedReader br = null;
            try {
                br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(dataFile));

                String line;

                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    String tmp[] = line.split(",");

                    if (tmp.length < 2) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    String firstName = tmp[0];
                    String lastName = tmp[1];

                    toSet.add(firstName + "\t" + lastName);
                }            

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (br != null) {
                    try {
                        br.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {}
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

V2 has 2 classes:

```
    package natalie.person.v2;

    import java.util.Objects;

    public class Person implements Comparable<Person> {

        public static Person parse(String line) {
            String[] tmp = line.split(",");
            if (tmp.length >= 2) {
                return new Person(tmp[0], tmp[1]);
            }
            return null;
        }

        private final String firstName;
        private final String lastName;

        public Person(String firstName, String lastName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            int hash = 7;
            hash = 79 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.firstName);
            hash = 79 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.lastName);
            return hash;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (obj == null) {
                return false;
            }
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
                return false;
            }
            final Person other = (Person) obj;
            if (!Objects.equals(this.firstName, other.firstName)) {
                return false;
            }
            if (!Objects.equals(this.lastName, other.lastName)) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Person o) {
            int result = 0;
            if (firstName != null) {
                result = firstName.compareTo(o.firstName);
                if (result == 0 && lastName != null) {
                    result = lastName.compareTo(o.lastName);
                }
            }
            return result;
        }        

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return firstName + '\t' + lastName;
        }        
    }




    package natalie.person.v2;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.HashSet;
    import java.util.Set;

    public class RunMe {
        public static void main(String[] args) {

            Set<Person> allPersons = new HashSet<>(); // or use java.util.TreeSet() to have the list sorted

            File dataFolder = new File("/home/agudkov/projects/rest/Natalie/data"); // change the path, pls

            for (File file : dataFolder.listFiles()) {            
                if (!file.getName().endsWith(".txt")) { // check the file has .txt ext
                    continue;
                }

                addPersonsFromFile(file, allPersons);
            }

            for (Person person : allPersons) {
                System.out.println(person);
            }
        }

        private static void addPersonsFromFile(File dataFile, Set<Person> toSet) {
            BufferedReader br = null;
            try {
                br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(dataFile));

                String line;

                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    Person person = Person.parse(line);

                    if (person == null) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    toSet.add(person);
                }            

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (br != null) {
                    try {
                        br.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {}
                }
            }
        }
    }
```